# Class not Found MySQL connector in Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have a question about MySQL connector - In my servlet i use connector-

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
```

as `String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";`

than in try block i create new Instance using

```
 Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
```

but after click on my "Search" button - i have an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I have my Mysql Connector in My Project `WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\` folder
and I have it in Projects build Path as well, but I still have an exception.

What shall i check or how can i get rid of this?

Thanks

Comment: What container are you using to run your server? If you are using Apache Tomcat, you should put the connector jar in the lib folder of the tomcat installation.

Comment: Which IDE you are using to create your project? How did you add this jar to buildpath?

Comment: @Eran - Please write an Answer - so I can accept your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Apache Tomcat for your server, you should put the connector jar in the `lib` folder of the Tomcat installation.